# Dynamic Style Sheet

Tags: asp.net, css

Is it possible to link a style sheet from code behind.

I want to link stylesheet_1 when the current day is < 15 th
and  stylesheet_2 when  current day is > 15 th

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use code behind. Just use Javascript to link according to the date in `onLoad()` function in the body like the following example:

```
var d = new Date();
var fileName
if(d.GetDate()<15){
 fileName="stylesheet_1"
}else{
 fileName="stylesheet_2"
}
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", fileName)

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but I think it will work.

Put this in the head of the aspx page

```
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="stylesheet" />
```

and then you can use the in the code behind to change it

```
stylesheet.Href = "stylesheet_1.css";
```